# How would someone list a all objects that have a certain value in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm working on building a page that will list off all of the models that contain the value of '1' for :category_id, here's the snippet from the page it's self

```
<h1>Discover the best of Games</h1>
<p>These are games we have featured and awarded</p>
<% @posts.find_by(category_id: 1) do |post| %>
  <h2>
    <%= link_to post.title, post %>
  </h2>
<% end %>
```

Notice the @posts.find_by(category_id: 1) do |post| is obviously wrong. It isn't displaying any posts and it comes up with the error of `undefined method`find_by' for nil:NilClass` So yes, I know .find_by is not correct. That much is obvious.

Here's the snippets from Schema.rb and post_controller.rb

Schema

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "category_id"
  end

  add_index "posts", ["category_id"], name: "index_posts_on_category_id"
```

Posts_controller (whole thing)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save
          redirect_to @post, notice: "Successfully created"
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @post.update(post_params)
            redirect_to @post, notice: "Post was successfully updated"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @post.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :category_id)
    end

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am very new to Rails and just getting the hang of the basics. Thanks.

Comment: Just as a note, `find_by` is a class method, not an instance method. So you can call it on the class `Post` but not on instance variables of that class.

Answer (score 4):

Edit:

```
Post.where(category_id: 1)
```

So:

```
<% Post.where(category_id: 1).each do |post| %>
  <h2>
    <%= link_to post.title, post %>
  </h2>
<% end %>
```

Using `find_by` is more for when you want a single object.  If you want a set of objects based on a set of conditions, use where.  Also, `find_by` can resolve methods like `find_by_category_id` based on what fields your model has, so `Post.find_by_title` and `Post.find_by_description` would magically work.  Again, I'd use `where` in these cases, but just noting for reference.

Another way of doing the same thing, assuming your models are set up appropriately, would be:

```
Category.find(1).posts
```

This would list all posts within the category 1.  This may be more explicit than `Post.where`, and an advantage to this version is if there's information about the category you would want to show on the page, such as the category name.  Then you already have the object:

```
@category = Category.find(1)
@posts = @category.posts

<h1>Posts for <%= @category.name %></h1>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  ... you know the rest
```

Anyway, hope that makes things a bit clearer in terms of how it's all put together and working.

Comment: Hmm... I seem to have gotten
undefined method `find_by_category_id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'll update my post to explain the difference, but use `where`.  Also, use `Post` and not `@posts`, as the former references the ActiveRecord class, whereas the latter represents an (likely uninstantiated) object

Comment: You are a savior. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` associations

```
def index
  @posts = Post.joins(:category).where('posts.category_id = ?', 1).order("posts.created_at DESC")
end
```

or if you want to avoid N+1, you can use `includes`

```
def index
  @posts = Post.includes(:category).where('posts.category_id = ?', 1).order("posts.created_at DESC")
end
```

I hope this help you.